# Azure AAD Role Based Authentication, User.IsInRole()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD role based authentication, I have added 2 roles ( Observer, Reader ) which are assigned to specific users which works fine.  The manifest file has these 2 new entries in it.  All the authentication is working normally, but I cannot get the User.IsInRole() to return true, always returns false

I have added the following code to the Startup.cs

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = SettingsHelper.ClientId,
                    Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,SettingsHelper.AADInstance, SettingsHelper.TenantId), 
                                                                                                                                                  PostLogoutRedirectUri = SettingsHelper.PostLogoutRedirectUri,

                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        // map the claimsPrincipal's roles to the roles claim
                        RoleClaimType = "roles",
                    },
}
```

When I query User.IsInRole("Observer") it returns false. I can see the claim in my debug session of User

{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: Observer}

But not able to access it, is this a common problem am I doing something wrong?

Here is my USER session var

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Would this work: `RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"`?

Comment: Hi that is just setting the variable RoleClaimType ?

Comment: Yeah, since your claim type is not "roles".

Comment: Hi  juunas I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: The `RoleClaimType` tells to the ClaimPrincipal which claims it should use for discovering the roles of the user. Your ClaimPrincipal contains a claim with type `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` and value `Observer`. I'm saying the type is configured wrong in your TokenValidationParameters.

Comment: Hi juunas think I know what you mean,  I changed RoleClaimType = "roles", to RoleClaimType = "role" in TokenValidationParameters but this did not work, User.IsInRole("Observer") saying False

Comment: Change RoleClaimType to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` not `role`.

Comment: Hi juunas changed the claim type to role, but still get false in User.IsInRole("Observer") thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

> {http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: Observer}

How did you add the custom role? Here are the steps which work for me to add the custom roles for your reference:

1. register the apps on Azure AD
2. modify its manifest to add the custom role like below:

```
"appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Orders",
      "id": "51e10148-16a8-432a-b86d-ef620c3e48ed",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Oders can rise a order request",
      "value": "Orders"
    },
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Admin",
      "id": "51e10148-16a8-432a-b86d-ef620c3e48ec",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Admins can manage roles and perform all task actions.",
      "value": "Admin"
    }
  ],
```

3. assign the role to users through the portal
4. using the code as in your orignal post to integrate the web app with Azure

```
  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        // map the claimsPrincipal's roles to the roles claim
                        RoleClaimType = "roles",
                    },
                });
```

Then we can get the roles as figure below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Fei Xue, I looked at your comments and I am doing exactly as you have when adding roles to the manifest this all works ok.  I have a screenshot of my debug session notice I don't have a {roles:Writer} as in yours.  Look forward to anybody's help.

Comment: Hi Fei Xue If you look at the above image this is what I get on my PC.  It is missing the role:Orders as in your picture

Comment: @user142617 I was testing the issue based on code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect.git). Could you reproduce this using this code sample? If not would you mind share the code to help us to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Hi  Fei Xue, I looked at your GitHub link but this has no roles code in there.  Did you look at my screenshot where I don't get any {roles: } at all and only get the Role:write at array [18]?

Comment: @user142617 Yes, but without the detailed code I am not able to narrow down the root cause.  To test the code sample on GitHub, we can add the custom code from my orignal post to test the roles. Or would you mind sharing a demo code sample to reproduce this issue? You can public it on the GitHub and please remove the sensitive data before you sync it on GitHub.

Comment: Hi  Fei Xue that is a great idea, I will take out all the sensitive code and put in GitHub I will do this over the xmas period, I will post the link when I have completed the github......You are very helpful

Comment: @RamppyDumppy To manage the roles using Azure Active Directory for the web app, you can refer [this link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims).

Answer (score 3):

By default, the claims mapping will map claim names in the old format to accommodate older SAML applications. The default mapping is 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role' instead of 'roles'. So you can use this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // This is required to be instantiated before the OpenIdConnectOptions starts getting configured.
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and the answer for me was to do what @juunas is saying in his comment on your original question here: [Azure AAD Role Based Authentication, User.IsInRole()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162255/azure-aad-role-based-authentication-user-isinrole?rq=1#comment69532054_41162255)

So literally change that line in your Startup.Auth.cs, so it now becomes:

```
TokenValidationParameters = new 
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
{   
    // map the claimsPrincipal's roles to the roles claim
    RoleClaimType = 
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
},
```

@juunas - thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can also use `RoleClaimType = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role`