# Unable to make [Authorize(Role="Administrator")] attribute working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, identityserver4, identity

I stuck on this problem since several days now and didn't find any solution.

First,  I created an SSO server with IdentyServer4, this part works, I can Authenticate

Second, I added Asp.Net.Identy to SSO server to manage users and roles and all of that into a persistent store. This part works too. I have created users, and roles and attached users to roles.

Third, I created an APS.NET MVC web application, secured by my SSO server and using OWIN.
I use Authorize attribute to secure controller and one of the method in this controller require to be Administrator.

The problem is, when I try to access this method, that the system goes into a loop, querying back and forth the ProfileService from SSO server.

And now, some code:

ProfileService into SSO server:

```
using IdentityServer.Models;
using IdentityServer4.Extensions;
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using IdentityServer4.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IdentityServer.Services
{
    public class ProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> _claimsFactory;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }

        public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
            var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);

            var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

            claims = claims.Where(claim => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type)).ToList();

            // Add custom claims in token here based on user properties or any other source
            claims.Add(new Claim("employee_id", user.EmployeeId ?? string.Empty));

            context.IssuedClaims = (List<Claim>)claims;
        }

        public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
            context.IsActive = user != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs into Web MVC application

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Owin.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Authorization.Infrastructure;
using IdentityModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication1.Startup))]

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Pour plus d'informations sur la configuration de votre application, visitez https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                SlidingExpiration = true
            });


            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            tokenHandler.InboundClaimFilter.Clear();

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "oidc",               
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                Authority = "https://localhost:5001", //adresse du serveur IdentityServer
                ClientId = "mvc", //nom du client au sens IdentityServer, doit être configuré dans la liste des client du fichier config.cs du serveur
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44354/Home/About", //redirection si login ok doit -être dans la liste des RefirectUris du client configuré sur le serveur
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44354/Home",
                ResponseType = "id_token token",
                Scope = "openid profile web_api",
                UseTokenLifetime = true,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                    {
                        var claims_to_exclude = new[]
                        {
                        "aud", "iss", "nbf", "exp", "nonce", "iat", "at_hash"
                        };

                        List<Claim> claims_to_keep =
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.Where(x => false == claims_to_exclude.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();
                        claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken != null)
                        {
                            claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                            //var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(EP_Configuration.epIdpUserInfoAccessPoint);
                            //var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);
                            //var userInfoClaims = userInfoResponse.Claims; // filter sub since we're already getting it from id_token
                            //claims_to_keep.AddRange(userInfoClaims);
                        }

                        var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                        ci.AddClaims(claims_to_keep);
                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket(
                            ci, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties
                        );
                    },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                    {
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                        {
                            var id_token = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token")?.Value;
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = id_token;
                        }

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
        }
    }
}
```

The secured method :

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
 public ActionResult About()
 {
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
    return View();
 }
```

When I click on the link in the page calling this method, the context passes to the server doesn't contains role to claim :

[image]

As you can see, TequestedClaimType is empty.

Another thing, when I get my user, it has no Role list attached to it:

[image]

Meanwhile, roles are into the Identiy of the Pincipal object :

[image]

I read a lot of post here and on other site, but nothing I tried so far resolve my issue.

Any help will be welcomed.

UPDATE 1:

I slightly changed my MVC client configuration server side, to add Roles scoped to  the client like that:
First I added this :

```
 public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResource("roles", new[] { "role" })
            };
        }
```

I added Adminstrator role to Alice user.
When I get token for user, token_Id is :

```
{
  "nbf": 1580127045,
  "exp": 1580127345,
  "iss": "https://localhost:5001",
  "aud": "mvc",
  "nonce": "637157238434573534.ZWU0MjNhYTItZDU5Ni00YjQxLThlNzYtYTRkYjAyNGYxZDA5NDZiZmZmZTktMzYwZS00NzliLThkN2UtZTJlZDNjYzRkZGUx",
  "iat": 1580127045,
  "at_hash": "JaDEsHC7VCXRuLghvo-pZQ",
  "sid": "47c344d69e4f20899c8c9f8594f5c47f",
  "sub": "99de568f-49d8-4dd1-b256-14c2647504cd",
  "auth_time": 1580121815,
  "idp": "local",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}

{
  "nbf": 1580127045,
  "exp": 1580130645,
  "iss": "https://localhost:5001",
  "aud": [
    "https://localhost:5001/resources",
    "web_api"
  ],
  "client_id": "mvc",
  "sub": "99de568f-49d8-4dd1-b256-14c2647504cd",
  "auth_time": 1580121815,
  "idp": "local",
  "name": "Alice Smith",
  "given_name": "Alice",
  "family_name": "Smith",
  "email": "AliceSmith@email.com",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "website": "http://alice.com",
  "address": "{ 'street_address': 'One Hacker Way', 'locality': 'Heidelberg', 'postal_code': 69118, 'country': 'Germany' }",
  "employee_id": "",
  "role": "Administrator",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "roles",
    "web_api"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

In my home controler this code always return false :

```
    if (!User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        throw new SecurityException("User is not an admin.");
```

And this call loop between the client and the server:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: `services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); });` try this

Comment: In SSO server StartUp.cs? Done, change nothing. And in Startup.cs from MVC webapp, service doesn't exists as it is not core.net but asp.net

Comment: No it didn't, meanwhile I understood how to add roles scoped to my mvc client

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly make it working by assembling different sources from the web.

As I fought the main problem was in the MVC client in the startup.cs.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:5001");

var userInfoResponse = await client.GetUserInfoAsync( new UserInfoRequest {Address = disco.UserInfoEndpoint, Token= n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken });

claims_to_keep.AddRange(userInfoClaims);
```

And the full class for memory:

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Owin.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Authorization.Infrastructure;
using IdentityModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using IdentityModel.Client;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication1.Startup))]

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Pour plus d'informations sur la configuration de votre application, visitez https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                SlidingExpiration = true
            });

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            tokenHandler.InboundClaimFilter.Clear();

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {

                AuthenticationType = "oidc",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                Authority = "https://localhost:5001", //adresse du serveur IdentityServer
                ClientId = "mvc", //nom du client au sens IdentityServer, doit être configuré dans la liste des client du fichier config.cs du serveur
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44354/Home", //redirection si login ok doit -être dans la liste des RefirectUris du client configuré sur le serveur
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44354/Home",
                ResponseType = "id_token token",
                Resource = "Role",
                Scope = "openid profile web_api roles",
                UseTokenLifetime = true,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                    {
                        var claims_to_exclude = new[]
                        {
                        "test"//"aud", "iss", "nbf", "exp", "nonce", "iat", "at_hash"
                        };

                        List<Claim> claims_to_keep =
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.Where(x => false == claims_to_exclude.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();
                        claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken != null)
                        {
                            claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                            var client = new HttpClient();
                            var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:5001");

                            var userInfoResponse = await client.GetUserInfoAsync( new UserInfoRequest {Address = disco.UserInfoEndpoint, Token= n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken });

                            var userInfoClaims = userInfoResponse.Claims; // filter sub since we're already getting it from id_token

                            claims_to_keep.AddRange(userInfoClaims);
                        }

                        var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                        ci.AddClaims(claims_to_keep);
                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket(
                            ci, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties
                        );
                    },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                    {
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                        {
                            var id_token = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token")?.Value;
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = id_token;
                        }

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching the web for hours :-(, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162255/azure-aad-role-based-authentication-user-isinrole):

```
RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
```

And here the whole code:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                        ClientId = clientId,
                        Authority = authority,
                        RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                        PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                        Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                                                    {
                                                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                                                            ValidIssuer = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0",
                                                            RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
                                                            NameClaimType = "name",
                                                    },
                        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                                        {
                                                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed  
                                        }
                }
        );

private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```